# Show Grand Total label on a stacked column chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Line and Stacked Column chart to which I want to add a "Grand Total" label at the top as the sum of the components in the stack.

I'd like to create a measure that sums the values in the Total column (in the data shown at the bottom of the screenshot) as "Grand Total" so that it can be applied to the chart.  I've had no luck using the SUM and SUMMARIZE functions so far.

Suggestions to achieve this are much appreciated.   Thanks in advance.

[image: Line and Stacked Column Chart]

[image: Detail data with Grand Total Measure on column CapExOpExNew[Total]]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a built-in way to do this at the moment but there are workarounds.

The idea is to use the combo Line and Stacked Column Chart and put the total as the line value and then hide the line.

Radacad explains it in more detail here:

[Showing the Total Value in Stacked Column Chart in Power BI](https://radacad.com/showing-the-total-value-in-stacked-column-chart-in-power-bi)

---

To get a grand total across all of the divisions, you can adjust your filter context as follows:

```
GrandTotal =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( CapExOpExNew[Total] ), ALL ( CapExOpExNew[Funding Division] ) )
```

Comment: This is what I wish to do as far as the chart is concerned, but, in order to do that, I need to sum the values using a measure to display it as Radacad explains.

Comment: If a simple `SUM(Table[Value])` measure doesn't work, you're going to need to provide some sample data. It's not at all clear from your question what your data looks like.

Comment: See amended post with additional details showing the result of using Sum(CapExOpExNew[Total]) for the Grand Total measure.    Instead of summing all values, it is producing three; one for each Funding Division, which I don't want.